How to properly close a Winform while there is a running Async Task?
(Check at the end of the question in Edit2 section, where the final working code from the accepted answer is posted)
I am creating a Winforms application (.Net 7), which depicts statistics on charts. The source of the statistical data is MySQL query, which runs in Async Task. After the query finishes the result datatable is bind to the chart.
When application is started there is a main Winform, where there are buttons, which start different Winforms or multiple instances of the same Winform.
My problem is that if for example in one of the child Winforms there is a running async MySQL query and I close that Winform with the "x" and now only the main Winform is on the screen, then when query finishes there is an exception System.NullReferenceException: 'Object reference not set to an instance of an object.' when the datatable is bind to the chart. Apparently closing the Winform is not enough to release all resources related to it (I don't mean killing the query, which naturally continues to run on MySQL server). My expectations were that if I close the form then all is finished with it.
What is the correct approach in such situations? How can I get rid of exceptions from a Winform which was closed while its task was not finished? Having such exceptions are affecting the user experience while users are working in other forms of the same application.
Simplified example of my code is below:
Public Class Form4
    Private Async Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click

        Dim TabCell As New DataTable
        'This is the statistical table

        Dim getStats As New Queries
        '"Queries " is a class containing query execution functions

        TabCell = Await Task().Run(Function() getStats.ExecQuery(parameters))
        'This is the asynchronous run of the task for query execution.
        'If the Winform is closed while this task is running...
        '...there is the mentioned exception in the line below:
        Chart1.DataSource = TabCell

        Chart1.Series.Clear()
        Chart1.Titles.Clear()
        'Further code for chart definition

    End Sub
End Class

The code of Queries class is below.
Public Class Queries

    Public Property connStr As String

    Public Function ExecQuery(date1 As Date, date2 As Date, queryString As String) As DataTable
        Dim dTab As New DataTable
        Dim SQL As New MySqlCommand
        Dim Adap As New MySqlDataAdapter

        Try
            MysqlConn.ConnectionString = connStr
            MysqlConn.Open()

            SQL.Parameters.AddWithValue("@date1", date1)
            SQL.Parameters.AddWithValue("@date2", date2)

            SQL.Connection = MysqlConn
            SQL.CommandText = queryString
            SQL.CommandTimeout = 1200

            Adap.SelectCommand = SQL
            Adap.Fill(dTab)

        Catch Err As MySqlException
            MsgBox("Error: " & Err.Number & " - " & Err.Message)
        Finally
            MysqlConn.Close()
            MysqlConn.Dispose()
        End Try

        Return dTab

    End Function

End Class

Edit: I am posting here the code from an answer that I received from a user 'Zch', but I don't know why it disappeared without a trace. This answer was very well structured and mostly useful. It explained how to deal with CancellationToken.
I implemented it and it worked like a charm. Now when the Winform is closed before the Async Task is finished there are no more exceptions.
The part that I can't figure out how to make it work is the implementation of CancellationToken in the query execution function in the Queries class. I need to say that the code in the Winform is working quite fine without the entries regarding the token in Queries class. Please check below the exact lines, which I don't understand what are designed to do.
If token.IsCancellationRequested Then
    token.ThrowIfCancellationRequested()
End If

Is this entry supposed to kill the query on MySQL server side? The author of the answer wrote following:

Make sure your query func can handle being canceled by providing
a CancelationToken and checking it periodically.

I don't know how to check that periodically.
The complete code from the answer that disappeared is shown below. It is a modification of my code with addition of entries for CancelationToken.
Public Class Form4
    Private cts As CancellationTokenSource

    Private Async Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
        cts = New CancellationTokenSource()
        Dim token As CancellationToken = cts.Token

        Try
            Dim TabCell As New DataTable
            'store the data from the query

            Dim getStats As New Queries
            'runs the queries

            TabCell = Await Task.Run(Function() getStats.ExecQuery(parameters, token), token)
            'Run the async query with the cancellation token

            If Not Me.IsDisposed Then
                Chart1.DataSource = TabCell
                Chart1.Series.Clear()
                Chart1.Titles.Clear()
                'Set up your data chart
            End If
        Catch ex As OperationCanceledException
            'The task was canceled, yay
        Catch ex As Exception
            'Handle other exceptions
        Finally
            cts.Dispose()
        End Try
    End Sub
    
    Private Sub Form4_FormClosing(sender As Object, e As FormClosingEventArgs) Handles MyBase.FormClosing
        If cts IsNot Nothing Then
            cts.Cancel()
        End If
    End Sub
End Class

Public Class Queries
    Public Function ExecQuery(parameters As Object, token As CancellationToken) As DataTable
        Dim dt As New DataTable

        'Simulate a long-running query
        For i As Integer = 1 To 10
            If token.IsCancellationRequested Then
                token.ThrowIfCancellationRequested()
            End If
            Threading.Thread.Sleep(420)
        Next

        'Your query logic goes here
        'Populate the DataTable

        Return dt
    End Function
End Class

Edit2: Below you can find the final working code from the accepted answer. There are some differences from the code in Edit section regarding the usage of Adapter.FillAsync functionallity of MySQL connector and also the addition of cts = Nothing after End Try and the removal of cts.Dispose() in Finally section.
Public Class Form4
    Private cts As CancellationTokenSource

    Private Async Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
    
        cts = New CancellationTokenSource()
        Dim token As CancellationToken = cts.Token

        Try
            Dim TabCell As New DataTable
            'store the data from the query

            Dim getStats As New Queries
            'runs the queries

            TabCell = Await Task.Run(Function() getStats.ExecQuery(queryString, token), token)
            'Run the async query with the cancellation token

            If Not Me.IsDisposed Then
                Chart1.DataSource = TabCell
                Chart1.Series.Clear()
                Chart1.Titles.Clear()
                'Set up your data chart
            End If
            
        Catch ex As OperationCanceledException
            'The task was canceled, yay
        Catch ex As Exception
            'Handle other exceptions
        End Try
        
        cts = Nothing
        
    End Sub
    
    Private Sub Form4_FormClosing(sender As Object, e As FormClosingEventArgs) Handles MyBase.FormClosing
        If cts IsNot Nothing Then
            cts.Cancel()
        End If
    End Sub
End Class

Public Class Queries
    Public Async Function ExecQuery(queryString As String, token As CancellationToken) As Task(Of DataTable)
        Dim dt As New DataTable
        Dim SQL As New MySqlCommand
        Dim Adap As New MySqlDataAdapter

        Try

            SQL.Connection = MysqlConn
            SQL.CommandText = queryString

            Adap.SelectCommand = SQL
            Await Adap.FillAsync(dTab, token)

            token.ThrowIfCancellationRequested()

        Catch Err As MySqlException
            MsgBox("Error: " & Err.Number & " - " & Err.Message)
        End Try

        Return dt
    End Function
End Class


Check https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.control.isdisposed?view=windowsdesktop-8.0

You should use the available async methods, passing a CancellationToken. You can then call [CancellationTokenSource].Cancel() when the Form is about to close (in OnFormClosing / OnFormClosed)

@Jimi I added new information in the question ("Edit" section), which comes from an answer that I received here, but was probably deleted by some reason. There is a nice implementation of CancellationToken. But I don't understand how properly to transfer the token to the MySQL query execution function.

@Jimi I am not exactly sure what did you mean to use the async methods in MySQL Connector documentation. Is this something which should replace Await Async when running the Task for execution of a function for MySQL query? I mean this: TabCell = Await Task().Run(Function() getStats.ExecQuery(parameters)). I am asking because in docs I can see following await proc.ExecuteNonQueryAsync(). Are both approaches supposed to run together or I just need to use the async methods of MySQL connector (which I don't prefer since too much code is to be changed and tested again)?

I mean exactly that: use the async methods provided by the library. So, e.g., await [Connection].OpenAsync([CancellationToken]), await [DataAdapter].FillAsync([...],[CancellationToken]), await [Command].ExecuteNonQueryAsync([CancellationToken]) and so on. There isn't much to change in the original code, you need to await those methods instead of just running them synchronously. Of course, passing the same CancellationToken to each, so each one can be cancelled when this becomes necessary, no matter where the current procedure is at when the cancellation is requested

@Jimi Should I expect that passing the CancellationToken to await [DataAdapter].FillAsync([...],[CancellationToken]) will kill the running query on MySQL server? I haven't found so far any assurance that this is possible to happen. If it is not possible than should I bother to run FillAsync instead of just Fill, when I can rely just on async call of query execution method (not to block the UI) and on cancellation in the Winform (not to have an exception) and to forget that the query is still running since my app does not need it anymore?

@Jimi maybe I don't understand properly the function of CancellationToken for my case. If I remove all MySQL async methods (like FillAsync, all tokens and form closing events in the last source code in my question and keep only If Not Me.IsDisposed Then just before the chart definition code than there is no more exception. So what purpose serves the CancellationToken as it does not kill the query on server side?

A CancellationToken is meant to cooperatively cancel a Task, so its current operations are terminated. In relation to querying a database, this implies that also the server side is involved (the implementation affects the infrastructure, when done correctly). The cancellation can be signaled with an exception. Hence you can terminate any operation, no matter what stage it's in. You have doubts about the actual functionality of the MySQL implementation? Then test it, see what happens when you cancel an operation that may (or may not) need server-side responsiveness

Your current implementation in ExecQuery() is meaningless, and checking for IsDisposed introduces a race condition you have no control over. Plus a bunch of other moving parts that can get in the way

It vanished without a trace because it got deleted by a mod (Hi @Da***a o/ ) and flagged as AI generated and I got angry AI generated mails, I don't have rep to post comments, and I won't even bother with code examples, but the gist is:
When working with CancellationToken, the goal is to allow tasks to be canceled gracefully, espec. long running tasks like db queries.
Check for Cancellation!
The lines:
If token.IsCancellationRequested Then
 token.ThrowIfCancellationRequested()

obv. check if a cancellation has been requested -> If so -> throw an OperationCanceledException which will stop the task execution. In my case I placed such checks at various points, for you, I'd put 'em in your long running tasks to make sure the task can be stopped asap if the form gets closed.
Few extra notes!
Local Execution: These checks help stop the local execution of the task in your app. e.g. if user closes the form, the task will stop running locally.
Server-Side: This does not stop the query on the MySQL server directly. As I said it only stops the task running in your app.
Periodic Checks: At risk to get accused of being an AI, I repeat myself: To use CancellationToken smoothly, insert checks at obv. points in your function, like in loops or after long operations within the task itself. Worked for me...
Ivaylo your suspicions are right:
CancellationToken doesn't kill the query on the server side. It stops the local task in your app. By checking token.IsCancellationRequested, you can stop long-running operations locally if the form is closed, which prevents exceptions.
Using async methods like OpenAsync, FillAsync, and ExecuteNonQueryAsync with cancellation tokens helps handle these operations gracefully and keep the UI responsive. By implementing periodic checks and using these async methods, your app should handle task cancellations gracefully. Voila we optimized, prevented exceptions and got smoother UX.
Imho it’s about managing the task within the app rather than going directly for the kill of a server side process. That part, as pointed out by @Jimi, is handled by the aforementioned async methods.
Hope this helps!
(Eagerly awaiting the ban hammer from an angry Croatian mod - or maybe she will be merciful in 2024? btw @Da***a I dunno what detection methods you guys use but just to prove my point... gbNuiQj.png @ i.imgur.com - happy banning/deleting! NHF)

StackOverflow is losing traffic not only because of ChatGpt, etc. services, but also because useless moderation and sour admins. My questions are attracting less and less attention, so why to ask here anymore? The good stuff is the huge database of history questions.

For the other users that reached this point you can find the answer's code in the "Edit" section of the question. The original answer with the code was deleted.

Btw, no need to do if cancellation checks with token.ThrowIfCancellationRequested(), this method does this check in its body. Method name implies that behavior:  ThrowIf...

TY, I was stumbling in dark when I had to at the very least try best I can to begin returning a favour to someone  who was there for me when I lost everything and was at my lowest, grieving multiple deaths,  bedridden from illness and desperate - alone and w/o income, & after starting to recover suddenly had to write code after looong period  of not touching anything more complex than occasional few line bat/ps/vbs/bash, hell, after few years of illness I struggled even with AHK, so thx for the hint, rather obvious now that you point it out, I feel lame :P                                    <3

@Zch, ahaha, that't not that bad, that mistake just adds some bits of CPU clock cycles. And i am glad, sir, to help you make code a bit cleaner, and get out of that darkness. =)

@Zch I think that there should be one modification in your solution in try catch finally end try block. Finally part should be removed and after End Try there should be cts = Nothing. Otherwise when closing the form normally after all async processes are finished the cts is disposed and in form closing event there is an exception that cts is disposed, when there is an attempt to close it.

@Ivaylo So if I'm getting you right, adding cts.Dispose and setting cts to Nothing after Try/End Try as you said (while checking for cancellation periodically in the Queries class and throw if it's requested) gets CancellationTokenSource properly disposed of and form closing handled gracefully, using async methods from MySQL Connector as @Jimi mentioned and pass the CancellationToken . Can't test right now, my CPU is @ 99% utilization (don't ask :P [Pro Tip: don't be me and not reboot your Windows for 4+ months])

@Zch I took the idea for setting cts to Nothing from Microsoft site - ypu can check there the last two examples with source codes. In my question I posted as Edit2 the latest update of the code taking into consideration all suggestions. It is working just fine and no issues at all. I can't check for cancellation periodically in Queries class, because it is one long query. So the check is done once it is already finished.
